# How to get the insights per campaign for multiple campaigns that belong to a specific ad account in a single call

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

We want to get the insights per campaign for multiple campaigns that belong to a specific ad account in a single call.

I am using the following http call and it returns me the correct insights(reach, impressions and clicks) and other data  per campaign for the last 30 days only.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/<ad_account>/campaigns?fields=name,status,insights{reach,impressions,clicks}&access_token=<access_token>`

How can I use the parameter date_preset so that I will be able to get the insights(reach, impressions and clicks) and other data  per campaign for lifetime?

If there is any other way to get the above insights for lifetime without using the date_preset please do not hesitate to advise me how to get them.

We wanted to let you know that our app is written in php.

Answer (score 1):

Because insights is an edge of the campaign object you can apply some filter parameters via dot on that edge, like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/<ad_account>/campaigns?fields=name,status,insights.date_preset(lifetime){reach,impressions,clicks}&access_token=<access_token>`

Or, if you want to check Insights with the time breakdown (three months, for example) and also take a look on the lifetime summary you can do it like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/<ad_account>/campaigns?fields=name,status,insights.default_summary(true).limit(3).date_preset(lifetime).time_increment(monthly){reach,impressions,clicks}&access_token=<access_token>`

```
{
     "name": "Campaign Name",
     "status": "Campaign Status",
     "insights": {
        "data": [
           {
              "reach": "149599",
              "impressions": "291917",
              "clicks": "13517",
              "date_start": "2019-01-11",
              "date_stop": "2019-01-31"
           },
           {
              "reach": "265556",
              "impressions": "456458",
              "clicks": "7915",
              "date_start": "2019-02-01",
              "date_stop": "2019-02-28"
           },
           {
              "reach": "233641",
              "impressions": "331600",
              "clicks": "4671",
              "date_start": "2019-03-01",
              "date_stop": "2019-03-31"
           }
        ],
        "paging": {
           "cursors": {
              "before": "BFR",
              "after": "AFT"
           },
           "next": "next link"
        },
        "summary": {
           "reach": "660772",
           "impressions": "1486924",
           "clicks": "32484",
           "date_start": "2019-01-11",
           "date_stop": "2019-05-06"
        }
     },
     "id": "000"
  }
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters#param